# In ElasticSearch how to check if a field exists then should return Boolean value( True or False ) only

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to check whether the data exists in the Document of Elasticsearch or not.
The response should be in Boolean 'True' Or 'False'.

For example, In Python:

```
Flag = ES.indices.exists(index=INDEX_Name)
```

Only returns `True` or `False`. like the above query, I want to know if there is any **query** in **PYTHON**. To check the data and return the Boolean value.

eg, Data set.

```
"_source":{
           name: "John",
           age: 31, 
           city: "New York"
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

To reach this goal, you need to implement this logic in your code. Elasicsearch by default returns data inside "hits" parameter in response. You need to define your criteria inside your query and search it. if any document returned, you would get true otherwise false. So your code in python would be something like this:

```
Flag = bool(len(ES.search(index=INDEX_Name, body=your_query).get("hits").get("hits") ))
```

Comment: You're Welcome! my friend.